# Declaring String with Chinese Characters

Tags: java, android, string, character, cjk

In my application I need to assign Chinese characters to a string to be diplayed on the screen.  If I simply do this...

```
String chinese = "我是你的朋友";
```

It says it doesn't support it and I have to save everything in UTF-8 format.  Will this mess my project up?  I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Thank you

Comment: Chinese in Java: http://www.chinesecomputing.com/programming/java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save all the files in UTF-8 format and also tell the Java compiler to use UTF-8 as the file encoding (refer to the documentation of your IDE or build tool), then it will work just fine.